# How can we display the textbox values as checked in checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist

Textbox value= orange,mango, Banana
It should be displayed as checked in checkbox
Checkbox ✓ orange
✓ mango
✓ banana
Apple

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To make a checkbox appear checked you add the checked attribute.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked>
```

However with the limited context you have given its hard to tell for sure if this is what you are looking for.

you can also add the disabled attribute if you want it to be view only.

```
<input type='checkbox' checked disabled>
```